# Is it possible to get the current position of a profile in the linkedin API?

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

I am trying to make an API to obtain information about the profiles of alumni from my university, specifically the current position and I have doubts about it.
The first thing would be if the current position is a data accessible through the LinkedIn API, I assumed that it is possible that it is a public data, but I don't know for sure.
The second thing I would like to know is if there are no problems in legal terms to be able to update the current position of the alumni using the API, since I have read a lot of people, but they have me somewhat confused. I'm not an expert on the subject of APIs, I'm just a student in practice.